# Trouble using local .csv in d3 in react

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am using **d3v4** I am trying to use this d3 element created by Harry Stevens: https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/f636199a46fc4b210fbca3b1dc4ef372.

I am trying to do it in react, and ofcourse I would make a local file like data.csv and than import like `import data from "./data.csv"` then use the data like `d3.csv(data, types, function(.....)` as in Stevens's code.

My console reads an error "uncaught (in promise)". After some research, I found that in v5 d3's d3.csv starts to return a promise, which means I have to use .then, which perplexes me because I am using d3v4, anyways, any insights on how to work around uncaught promise?

Similar answers I referenced but did not work: [Dynamic loading data using d3.csv in D3 v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941618/dynamic-loading-data-using-d3-csv-in-d3-v5?rq=1)

Comment: Try `d3.csvParse(data)`. I think d3.csv() expects a url, not a string of data. You may need to turn `data` into a string, I'm not sure what the data type will be from the import.